# Share internet connection to ethernet and hosted network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have used my iPhone as the source of internet using USB connected to my laptop (Local Area Connection). How do I share the connection to:

1. a computer connected via Ethernet
2. a hosted network (laptop's hotspot)

[image]

I managed sharing the connection to the ethernet one by bridging them. But the bridged connection is missing that **Sharing** tab so I can just share it to my personal hotspot.

[image]

"Lord Cyrus" is the laptop hotspot I created.

Answer (score 0):

3rd party tools make this much easier

Try using connectify hot spot. It does all the work for you and ou can share internet easily witch just few mouse clicks

[Download connectify here](http://www.connectify.me/hotspot/)